# Show main windows after the Splash Screen in C++ - QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application with a Splash Screen. I need to show the splash screen to appear before the main window appears and wait 3.5 seconds. Once it finished now I need to show the main window.

Here is the code what I have tried,

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTimer>
#include "game.h"
#include "player.h"
#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QObject>


Game *game;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    //Splash screen
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
    splash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/Images/1.JPG"));
    splash->show();

    //main window
    game = new Game();

    QTimer::singleShot(3500, splash, SLOT(close()));

    QTimer::singleShot(3500, game, SLOT(show()));

    game->displayHome();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Game Class**

```
Game::Game(QWidget *parent)
{

    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,600);
    setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage("img.png")));

    setScene(scene);
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setFixedSize(800,600);

    show();
     qDebug() << "yoyoyoy";

     score = new Score();
    health = new Health();


    connect(this->health,SIGNAL(crash()),this,SLOT(gameover3()));
}

void Game::displayHome()
{
    logo = new Logo();
    scene->addItem(logo);

    playButton = new Menubuttons(QString("Play"));
    int bxPos = this->width()/2 - playButton->boundingRect().width()/2;
    int byPos = 275;
    playButton->setPos(bxPos,byPos);
    connect(playButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(startGame()));
    scene->addItem(playButton);

    instructions = new Menubuttons(QString("Instructions"));
    int axPos = this->width()/2 - instructions->boundingRect().width()/2;
    int ayPos = 350;
    instructions->setPos(axPos,ayPos);
    connect(instructions,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(instruct()));
    scene->addItem(instructions);

    quitButton = new Menubuttons(QString("Quit"));
    int qxPos = this->width()/2 - quitButton->boundingRect().width()/2;
    int qyPos = 425;
    quitButton->setPos(qxPos,qyPos);
    connect(quitButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
    scene->addItem(quitButton);

    scene->removeItem(inst);
}
```

But it appears both at the same time. How can I fix that?

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh, I am sorry sir. I still didn't check. I will check and let you know sir. Thanks for your answer sir

Comment: @eyllanesc It is not working sir. `diaplayHome()` is a method in Game class. It initializes UI that need to open in the window. I am making a Game sir

Comment: then provide a [mcve], show your Game class.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added game class. can you check that sir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe is not reproduced by the complete example below

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qmainwindow.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qtimer.h>
#include <qsplashscreen.h>

QMainWindow* game;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
    splash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/StackOverflow/SplashScreen"));
    splash->show();

    game = new QMainWindow();       

    QTimer::singleShot(3500, splash, SLOT(close()));
    QTimer::singleShot(3500, game, SLOT(show()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Running this displays a splash screen for 3.5 seconds followed by the main window. The issue may be your implementation for the `Game` class or the member function `displayHome()`.

### Edit

After your edit with the `Game` class definition and implementation it is clear the problem is calling `show()` at the end of the `Game::Game()` constructor. This causes `game` to display immediately upon construction, the subsequent call to `show()` in `QTimer::singleShot(3500, game, SLOT(show()))` is redundant upon the already visible object. To fix this simply remove `show()` from the `Game` constructor, i.e. it should be

```
Game::Game(QWidget *parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage("img.png")));

    setScene(scene);
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setFixedSize(800, 600);
}
```

Comment: I have added that `splash screen` code. Previously It is `Game *game = new Game();` to start the game only. I will check this and let you know sir. Thank you for your answer sir.

Comment: @TechGuy If you can't reproduce the behavior I describe in the answer with the *exact* code here then you need to look at how you are compiling and executing the program as the problem is not in the code.

Comment: @TechGuy Don't forget to accept if this correctly answers your question (with edits)

Comment: I still didn't check this. I will check and let you know. Thanks for your answer and the support.